# Правильно ли я перевожу в код условия задачи. JAVA

Tags: java

Решаю задачи в Java. Возникают трудности в понимании формулировок. 
Посмотрите, пож-а, правильно ли я понимаю и отображаю в виде кода условия задачи? Спасибо.

> 1) Класс SpamAnalyzer должен конструироваться от массива строк с ключевыми словами.

То есть в теле класса создаем конструктор, принимающий на вход массив строк

```
public SpamAnalyzer(String[] text) {

    }
```

> 2) Объект этого класса (SpamAnalyzer) должен сохранять в своем состоянии этот массив строк в приватном поле keywords.

Экземпляр класса будет просить на вход массив строк, который он сохранит в приватном массиве строк keywords.

```
private String[] keywords;
    public SpamAnalyzer(String[] text) {
        this.keywords = text;

    }
```

> 3) Класс NegativeTextAnalyzer должен конструироваться конструктором по-умолчанию.

То есть в классе конструктор не создается, и в Main он будет иметь вид

```
NegativeTextAnalyzer negativeTextAnalyser = new NegativeTextAnalyzer() // ничего на вход не просит
```

Comment: Да, все вполне соответствует, однако конструктор `NegativeTextAnalyzer()` может быть объявлен в классе и содержать какой-то код.

Comment: @Nofate, а зачем таки создавать конструктор и код туда писать? В условии же этого, вроде, нет...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ну это же только отрывки из задачи, как я понимаю.

Comment: @Nofate, так-то да, но, я думаю, можно трактовать цитату `должен конструироваться конструктором по-умолчанию` как явное указание на то, что его писать не надо, он должен создаться "молча" и класс предполагается использовать через какие-то его методы. Но это, конечно, лишь моя интерпретация) Мне кажется что безаргументный публичный конструктор с кодом внутри уже не назвать дефолтным, созданным "в тихую"

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, в общем да, соглашусь